# WebSphere: Adding bin directories to the classpath

Tags: java, websphere

Is it possible to add a directory with classes or other sub-directories with classes (and not a jar) to my classpath?

I tried doing this, but haven't succeeded. I think it is possible with bootclasspath perhaps, but haven't managed to get it right. If so, does the dir have to be of name "bin"?

Happy for any details, since haven't found a lot about this over the interenet.
I came across an IBM page, saying "Specifies bootstrap classes and resources for JVM code. This option is only available for JVM instructions that support bootstrap classes and resources."
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzatz%2F51%2Fadmin%2Fhelp%2Furun_rconfproc_jvm.html

---

1. Is "bootclasspath" the way to go? Can this option help me set a directory in the classpath?
2. If so, how to use this option (should dir name be "bin")?
3. The ibm page says "This option is only available for JVM instructions that support bootstrap classes and resources" - Will reflection calls from the regular classpath work if what I am looking for in reflection is in the bootclasspath?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Websphere Application Server has a functionality named [Shared Libraries](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v6.doc/topics/tlibraryv6.html) that are folders of the file-system that can contain JAR archives, class files and Resources files (like properties). After deploying they can be added to the classpath of any installed applications.

They are great for grouping libraries that are used by several applications, and to remove resources files our of the applications source code.

Comment: Great, but may question is about adding a directory with classes to the classpath - not jar files or whatever. Is it possible to do with WebSphere?

Comment: Shared libraries can contain class files according to this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.1/en/shared-library.html